# How to access the cluster with other user if cluster creator is unknown?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

We have created the EKS cluster with one user and forgot that user information. We have run our production site in that cluster and we need to access that cluster. But when tried to access that cluster with admin user we faced the issue in the below image .

[Your current user or role does not have access to Kubernetes objects on this EKS cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fBjh.png)

Our question is , how to access the cluster with admin user if cluster created user was destroyed or forgotten ?

Comment: Did you try that? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-object-access-error/

Comment: yes tried, I don't have access to edit aws-auth ConfigMap in that cluster

Comment: How has your cluster been created? Did you use IaC? If yes, the IAM User which created it should be in the `system:masters` ConfigMap.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `IAM User` who created the EKS Cluster has full admin access to the EKS Cluster.

If this `IAM User` has been deleted, you could try to re-create it (with the same name). The generated `ARN` should then be the same as the `IAM User` you mistakenly deleted.

With that workaround, I believe you should be able to gain back access and modify the `ConfigMap`.